# About ggplot2: Rotate geom_point shape & Show geom_text above the line

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, rstudio, visualization

Good Morning.

I am trying to plot using a ggplot2 package but facing a problem below:

To make it more understandable, here is the target image that I want to make.

[image]

Just like the image, I want to do the followings:

1) Put a text 'median' above the dashed line so that it is ok to see the character clearly.

2) Rotate the degree of triangle (Not ^ ^ but < >) so that it makes sense.

To achieve the above, I've done so far with the codes:

```
# binding the data, defining the x and y aesthetics, title, labels
w_plot <- ggplot(
  data = com_mal, 
  aes(x = reorder(name, -median_age),  y = median_age)
)

labels = c('5 yrs old', 10, 15, 20, 25, 30)

w_plot + 
  geom_linerange(
    aes(ymin = q1_age, ymax = q3_age),
    color = "#76bde0", 
    size = 6, 
    alpha = 0.7
  ) + 
  geom_point(fill = "#ed3324", colour = "white", size = 4, shape = 21) +
  geom_text(aes(y = 9, x = 15, label = '25th')) +
  geom_text(aes(y = 20, x = 15, label = '75th percentile')) +
  geom_text(aes(y = 30, x = 22, label = 'median')) +
  geom_point(aes(y = 8.25, x = 15), shape = 17) +
  geom_point(aes(y = 21.75, x = 15), shape = 17) +
  geom_point(aes(y = 29, x = 21.9), fill = "#ed3324", colour = "white", size = 4, shape = 21) +
  geom_hline(aes(yintercept = 5), linetype = 'dotted') +
  geom_hline(aes(yintercept = 10), linetype = 'dotted') +
  geom_hline(aes(yintercept = 15), linetype = 'dotted') +
  geom_hline(aes(yintercept = 20), linetype = 'dotted') +
  geom_hline(aes(yintercept = 25), linetype = 'dotted') +
  geom_hline(aes(yintercept = 30), linetype = 'dotted') +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(5, 30, by = 5), position = 'right', labels = labels) +
  coord_flip() +
  labs(title = 'Youngest Male Names',
       subtitle = 'By estimated median age for Americans alive as of Jan 1. 2014',
       x = NULL, y = NULL, caption =  'SOURCE: SOCIAL SECURITY ADMINISTRATION') +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(face = 'bold', size = 16),
        panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks = element_blank(), plot.caption = element_text(size = 10))
```

[image]

Thank you very much!

Comment: please add some data. so we can reproduce the plot. instead of `geom_text` try `geom_label()`.

Comment: Instead of `geom_point`, use `geom_polygon` where you in advance have calculated the position of each corner of the two triangles. The y-coordinate in your example is centered around `y = 11` (if I have counted correctly).

Comment: Thank you for your all answers! :)

Answer (score 4):

For the triangles, you could use `geom_text()` instead, setting the family argument to a font that supports the character, and for the label use `geom_label()`:

```
 geom_text(label = "▶", size = 3, family = "HiraKakuPro-W3")
 geom_label(aes(y = 4, x = 10, label = 'median'), fill = "grey92", label.size = NA)
```

`label.size` removes the outline of the label, and "grey92" is (approximately?) the color of the background.

If you want the dotted line to be behind the label, you should add `geom_label()` to the plot *after* the line. (Also notice that you can add all the dotted lines in the same line of code.)

```
w_plot + 
  geom_linerange(
    aes(ymin = q1_age, ymax = q3_age),
    color = "#76bde0", 
    size = 6, 
    alpha = 0.7
  ) + 
  geom_point(fill = "#ed3324", colour = "white", size = 4, shape = 21) +
  geom_text(aes(y = 9, x = 15, label = '25th')) +
  geom_text(aes(y = 20, x = 15, label = '75th percentile')) +
  geom_text(aes(y = 8.25, x = 15),label = "◀", size = 3, 
            family = "HiraKakuPro-W3") +
  geom_text(aes(y = 21.75, x = 15),label = "▶", size = 3, 
            family = "HiraKakuPro-W3") +
  geom_point(aes(y = 29, x = 21.9), fill = "#ed3324", colour = "white", 
             size = 4, shape = 21) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = seq(5, 30, by = 5), linetype = 'dotted') +
  geom_label(aes(y = 30, x = 22, label = 'median'), 
             fill = "grey92", label.size = NA) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(5, 30, by = 5), 
                     position = 'right', labels = labels) +
  coord_flip() +
  labs(title = 'Youngest Male Names',
       subtitle = 'By estimated median age for Americans alive as of Jan 1. 2014',
       caption =  'SOURCE: SOCIAL SECURITY ADMINISTRATION') +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(face = 'bold', size = 16),
        panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks = element_blank(), plot.caption = element_text(size = 10))
```

Comment: @supremed14: can you add the output of `dput(com_mal)` to your question so others can reproduce the plot? Please also mark Luca's post as an answer to help future readers. Thanks!