# Rotate geom_point based on dataframe in ggplot2 -- R

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, graph, rotation

How can I rotate points in ggplot2 based on the column of a dataframe? `aes()` doesn't take an angle argument. For example, given the following dataframe:

```
nums = c(20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90, 100)
bot = c(5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5)
top = c(40,80,120,160,200,240,280,320,360)
bot_nums = data.frame(nums, bot, top)
```

How can I rotate each point by the `top` column if I plot them at `(nums, bot)`?
If `geom_point()` does not allow for this, is there something within ggplot2 that will?

Edit: To clarify, I would like to rotate about `(nums, bot)`, not around the origin. Meaning, I would like to rotate the point in place so that it does not move, its orientation/the direction it is facing just changes.

Code to plot:

```
ggplot(bot_nums, aes(nums, bot, size=50)) +
geom_point(shape = "\u2BCA")
```

Comment: Rotate against `0,0`?

Comment: @Park I just edited to clarify. I want to rotate it in place, so with respect to itself (not sure if that is the correct way to say it). I don't want the point to move about the origin.

Comment: If you are trying to do the same as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39881984/rotate-and-resize-symbol-ggplot or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51854352/about-ggplot2-rotate-geom-point-shape-show-geom-text-above-the-line, you'll find ggplot doesn't make it easy to orient the plotting character.

Comment: @MrFlick I gave the basic plotting code. I am using ggplot. I had seen those posts but the answers did not really bring me any closer to what I am looking for so I decided to ask it myself.

Comment: Maybe `"\u2BCB"` solves your problem

Comment: @ViníciusFélix unfortunately not. I need to be able to rotate each point by a specific, different amount (0 - 360, in degrees) specified by a dataframe column such as the one in the example.